# wkhtmltopdf not working when it's included in footer file

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

Why in wkhtmltopdf Javascript not working when it's included in footer file?

cmd:
wkhtmltopdf --footer-html footer.html --zoom 1.2 out.html out.pdf

footer.html content:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {    
      document.getElementById('foot').innerHTML = 'test';
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="foot"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

wkhtmtopdf 0.12.1 (with patched qt)

system: win 8.1 x64

Comment: Have you tried simpler javascript? Without the binding for example.

Answer (score 0):

It was missing DOCTYPE.When I put it JS began to work